# Orbot installation error. Unknown error code in installation: "-24"

Tags: orbot, help, mobile, update, troubleshooting

Had Orbot working fine for a long time, then made an error in deinstalling it. Wanted to reinstall, no way. Installation starts, and stops/finishes with "unknown error code:-24" in Google Play.

Other ways to install (s. below) failed also. All in the same manner. Installation starts, and fails. App not installed. But installing other software is seamless. Even De-install and Re-install is no problem. It's just Orbot. Therefore, I assume some old files/directories/reminiscences/leftovers from the old installation prevent reinstallation by "unknown install error code: -24".

If so: What paths/files/settings to look for / clean up / change?
If not: What's the solution?

I'm clueless and need help.

HW: Rooted Galaxy tab 3 lite

Tried installations:
fiewalls down, net connection Wifi, tried from google play, from f-droid, via Orweb calling Google Play to install Orbot, as local apk (14.0.7 and 14.0.7.3) on SdCard both with packet installer, and even with adb install bypass in a terminal... No luck at all:

HELP, PLEASE!

Tankx in advance

Comment: Do you use CyanogenMod?